# How to config prettier not to auto-wrap markdown table?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, prettier

Prettier's auto-format feature for table in markdown is great, however it also auto-wrap the table, which leads to awful readability when the table has wide columns.

So can I config prettier not to auto-wrap markdown tables?
How?

Answer (score 1):

i found only solution is to add `<!-- prettier-ignore -->` above table you can find out here. https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/762